# Parentheses working wrong when using Angular pipe on Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

In my angular project I'm using "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1" for translation from english into Persian.

```
<label class="code">
  ({{'User.' + currency | translate}})
 </label>
```

when using parentheses wrapping translation pipe for Persian language parentheses are appearing in wrong way in Safari (IOS) [image]

but in chrome it is working as expected [image]

How can I make it work right?

Comment: if it's working in chrome as expected, where isn't it working?

Comment: On Safari it working in wrong way

Comment: that's the sort of information that makes it possible to help :p

Comment: @Bravo what do you mean? I am facing this issue iOS, therefore cannot figure out how can I make it work in a right way.

Comment: What about putting the text inside the parenthesis in a new element (eg. a span)? For example: `<label>(<span>{{..}}</span>)</label>`; or perhaps a Unicode zero-width space / non-joiner in place of the span separation?

Comment: @HovhannesGevorgyan - I mean that your original question said "it doesn't work but it works in Chrome" - adding "it doesn't work in Safari" means that we now know where it doesn't work, we didn't until you added that information 2 minutes after I asked where doesn't it work ... sorry, is that too difficult to understand? I can type slower

Comment: @Bravo initially it was written that the problem existed in iOS and as the Safari works only in IOS, we can assume that it was clear that the problem is on Safari only. For more clarification we changed the title. No need to type slower. Keep the speed)

Comment: initially there was ZERO mention of Safari

Comment: @Bravo I hope you have already understood what is the question and I would like to concentrate in main question, if you can help it will be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in span tag and add a style with display: inline-block.

```
<label class="code">
  <span style="display: inline-block">({{'User.' + currency | translate}})</span>
</label>
```

It should solve your problem.